# How to get verified to get Apple education pricing?

Tags: apple-store

I just graduated high school a few months ago, and got accepted to a college. However, my enrollment is not happening until October so I dont have a personal institution email.

So, is it possible for me to qualify for the educational discounts that Apple offers before the enrollment?

Comment: Contact Apple - it will be their decision.

Answer (score 0):

Apple puts much of the information online so you can do some research before you call or go in to shop.

- https://www.apple.com/education/college-students/

Depending on which region you will be purchasing, the college bundles and limited time deals are often the steepest discount and best value for some accessories like AirPods around.

Here is the current US program: https://www.apple.com/us-edu/store

The pre sales phone support can help if you’re not certain if you have been accepted and Apple does audit these purchases later so you would need to show them your offer letter or other documentation should your purchase be audited after you pay the discounted price. There are limits on how many systems you can purchase annually as well.